# How to sort numbers in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

```
print "@_\n";
4109 4121 6823 12967 12971 14003 20186
```

How do I sort it in Perl?

Using `@sorted = sort(@_);` gives me an alphabetical ordering:

```
13041 13045 14003 20186 4109 4121 6823
```

How do I get a numerical ordering? Does Perl have built-in functions for merge-sort, insertion-sort, etc.?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can pass a custom comparison function to Perl's sort routine. Just use:

```
@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @unsorted;
```

The `sort` function accepts a custom comparison function as its first argument, in the form of a code block. The `{...}` part is just this code block (see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html ).

`sort` will call this custom comparison function whenever it needs to compare two elements from the array to be sorted. `sort` always passes in the two values to compare as `$a`, `$b`, and the comparison function has to return the result of the comparison. In this case it just uses the operator for numeric comparison (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators ), which was probably created just for this purpose :-).

Solution shamelessly stolen from "[Perl Cookbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=hP4IRp8xwTkC&lpg=PP1&dq=perl%20cookbook&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q&f=false)", Chapter 04 Sub-chapter 15 (buy the book - it's worth it!)

Comment: I'd take that link down, it is distributing copyrighted material without the holder's consent. You could recommend the original work (the Perl Cookbook, Christiansen and Torkington) instead.

Comment: It seems to be a consensus on [Perl] tag that linking to pirated copies of O'Reilly books (or any books) is Bad. Editing to remove

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize the link was to pirated material. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Google books often has nice non-pirated material suitable for linking.

Answer (score 13):

Supply a comparison function to [`sort()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html):

```
# sort numerically ascending
my @articles = sort {$a <=> $b} @files;

# sort numerically descending
my @articles = sort {$b <=> $a} @files;
```

The default sort function is `cmp`, string comparison, which would sort `(1, 2, 10)` into `(1, 10, 2)` . `<=>` , used above, is the numerical comparison operator.

Answer (score 8):

Perl's `sort` by default sorts alphabetically in ASCII order. To sort numerically you can use:

```
@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @_;
```

Comment: @Lazer: See my explanations (I submitted the same answer, just slightly later;-)).

Answer (score 6):

This is a Perl FAQ.  From the command line:

```
perldoc -q sort
```

[perlfaq4: How do I sort an array by (anything)?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-an-array-by-(anything)%3f)

Answer (score 5):

```
@l = (4109, 4121, 6823, 12967, 12971, 14003, 20186, 1, 3, 4);
@l = sort { $a <=> $b } @l;
print "@l\n"; # 1 3 4 4109 4121 6823 12967 12971 14003 20186
```

You have to supply your own sorting subroutine `{ $a <=> $b }`

Comment: What is `{ $a <=> $b }`? An [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)? Perhaps elaborate a little bit in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I’ve forgotten everything I once knew about perl. It seems it’s called a “block”, and the a/b variables are “package global” variables sort provides when using the block.

Comment: @PeterMortensen you asked someone to elaborate on their answer ten years after they wrote it, and was not the accepted answer; are you sure that was the best use of your or their time? (And yes, I'm aware of the irony of calling you out on this 3 years later)

Answer (score 3):

You can predefine a function which should be used to compe values in your array.

`perldoc -f sort` gives you an example:

```
# Sort using explicit subroutine name
sub byage {
   $age{$a} <=> $age{$b};  # Presuming numeric
}
@sortedclass = sort byage @class;
```

The `<=>` operator is used to sort numerically.

```
@sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} @unsorted;
```

Answer (score 1):

You find here (and in a lot of other places) that the way to sort a numeric array is:

```
@sorted_array = sort { $a <=> $b } @unsorted_array;
```

Now you try it, and you get an error: "Can't use "my $a" in sort comparison"! (This is because you have already declared '$a', using 'strict.pm'). But then, you can't use non-declared variables either since they will be rejected as undefined! So, you might feel trapped in an impasse.

Neither *perldoc.perl.org*, nor most other places mention that '$a' ***and*** '$b' ***are reserved (tokens) for this use***! (This of course when one uses 'strict', which one should. And which is quite crazy, because 'a' and 'b' are among the most common short variables used in programming, and logically so!)