# Why doesn't Perl sort numbers in numerical order?

Tags: perl

I have to write code that takes user input and turns it into an array, then have the largest number multiply everything in the array. When I input any number <=9 the code runs fine. But when I enter anything over 9 the code "drops" it as the largest value, if that makes any sense.

In my code, I sorted the array then had the last value (the largest) multiply the whole array

input numbers (user input): 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8 10

final (after being sorted and multiplied: 8, 80, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64

You can see that 10 is the largest number (and should be the last because of the sort), but for some reason 10 is pushed to the first position and 8 is made the last/largest value. If I were to add 9 anywhere in the input, 9 would be made the last/largest number instead of 8, as it should.

I even tried this on an online complier and the result was the same

Why is anything greater than 9 doing this? And how do I fix this?

Also, code looks bad because this is my first day touching Perl lol

```
print("input numbers: ");
$nums = <STDIN>;

@converted = split(' ', $nums); #turned user input into an array

@sorted = sort(@converted);

$multi = @sorted[-1]; #puts the last/largest number of the array in $multi

foreach $x (@sorted){ #loops through the array and multiplies everything by the last/largest value
    $x = $x * $multi
}

print("final: ");
print join(', ', @sorted); #just added commas to make it readable
```

I know there's an easier way to do this with the min max stuff but it wasn't working when I tried it

Comment: Seems like it's sorting alphabetically: 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: Then wouldn't 8 be first and 2 be last?

Comment: Not sure why you think that `8` sorts alphabetically ahead of `2`.

Comment: I am not a programmer. I just do this stuff to get a grade in class. Unless alphabetical means something else than what I think, then how wouldn't it? Originally I thought if you sort it that it should be "1, 2, 3...10." My understanding of what alphabetically sorted was that eight comes before two because E comes before T. But alphabetical sort clearly means something else

Comment: Okay, I just looked up what alphabetical sorting is lol. That makes more sense then

Comment: This is often called *ASCIIabetical* sorting because it's usually not what you want, and can lead to other problems, like capital letters sorting differently from their lower-case counterparts.

Comment: You want to sort numerically. See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort

Comment: "My understanding of what alphabetically sorted was that eight comes before two because E comes before T." Ah, that's known in programming as "telephone book sorting." Perl's default alphabetical sort is by code point order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort numbers in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574336/how-to-sort-numbers-in-perl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sort` sorts lexically by default.

This places `ba` before `i` because `b` comes before `i`, and
this places `10` before `9` because `1` comes before `9`.

To sort numerically, use

```perl
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @unsorted;
```

or

```perl
use Sort::Key qw( nsort );

my @sorted = nsort @unsorted;
```